Pressure inside a bubble/drop of water due to surface tension
I was studying problems in capillary action in fluid mechanics and I have a fundamental doubt. Is the excess pressure inside a bubble/spherical fluid body caused by surface tension, the same all throughout the bubble/spherical fluid body or is it different at different points? Also is it constant in a bubble and not constant in a spherical fluid body? And where exactly is the excess pressure 2T/R or 4T/R, on the periphery or right at the centre of the bubble?
